# iCal from API GET AirBnb returns "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden" ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, icalendar

I want to import dates from iCal that provides AirBnb.
I am developing ASP.NET MVC app with some nugget called iCal.Net.

The code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        const string airbnbCalendar = "https://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/1111111.ics?s=zkdjhfkjsdzkhfkkjsadjkfhskjdfhjk";

        Calendar calendar;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            byte[] file = null;

            file = client.DownloadData(airbnbCalendar);
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(file);
            calendar = Calendar.Load(stream);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I am getting an error on line client.DownloadData(airbnbCalendar):

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

I've googled a little bit, and I found that for some reason I must "imitate" a web browser for that request. Here is the link to the [airbnb forum](https://community.withairbnb.com/t5/Help/importing-ical-to-my-web-site-as-I-get-a-403-error/td-p/121289)

How can I transform my request to the CURL request? In order to airbnb gives me proper data?

P.S. When I copy airbnb url to the browser, I get proper .ics file

For security reason I've altered url address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `User-Agent` is transferred via request-header. So add an appropriate header to the webclient like shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.headers?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically what I added and it worked:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36";` to my `HttpWebRequest` object in order to download iCal data from AirBnb